# Consider $U(s,z)=s^z\sum \limits _{n=0}^\infty \binom{z}{n}u_ns^n.$ Which of the following phrases are correct grammatically?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, article-writing

Let's consider $U(s,z)=s^z\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{z}{n}u_ns^n.$ Which of the following phrases are correct grammatically?

- The function $U(s,z)$ is the product of an entire function *and* a series of an entire functions, or
- The function $U(s,z)$ is the product of an entire function *with* a series of an entire functions, or
- The function $U(s,z)$ is the product of an entire function **by** a series of an entire functions.

Comment: What exactly  is $u_n?$

Comment: @IgorRivin That's not important; what's important is whether this question is on-topic on this site ... The tag `article-writing` seems to be applicable here.

Comment: I guess the first amd the second one should be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't about grammar, but about idiom (which is much more important than grammar if you want to be understood - your three sentences are actually all grammatically correct, but they don't all convey the intended idea).

Firstly, when you say "denote", it would be much more idiomatic to say "write" or "set". "Denote" is quite a difficult term to pin down except in the case when we are talking about what a symbol means (as opposed to what we mean by a symbol).

If $z = x \times y$, then $z$ is the product of $x$ **and** $y$. Neither $x$ **by** $y$ nor $x$ **with** $y$ works very well in this sense. It is idiomatic to say that $z$ is the result of multiplying $x$ **by** $y$.

In all your examples, when you say "series", you should say "sum of a series". I can see that this is very confusing: we distinguish between sequences $s_n$ and series $\sum_n s_n$, but when we talk about the sum of the series we have to say we mean the sum (I think when we are talking about the series, we are implicitly talking about its partial sums).

The phrase "series of entire functions" doesn't read very well to me. I would have written something more explicit: like "sum of a series of terms, each of which is an entire function of $z$" (or whatever the parameter is).

Comment: You said that the three sentences are all grammatically correct, but they don't all convey the intended idea. But you didn't explain what are the differences among the three and which one conveys which idea. And do you think this is question is more suitable here than e.g. on [the English site](https://english.stackexchange.com/) - I'm not really sure.

Comment: I don't think you will get a good answer on a discussion about English in general, because this is about the use of English in mathematics. What I am trying to say is that the three sentences are all grammatically correct, but only the one with "and" would be used by a native writer of mathematical English. The other two just aren't what anyone would write (with a bit of doubt about the one with **by**, but I would recommend you stick with **and**).